# Contraints on parameters in JAGS/Winbugs

Tags: constraints, winbugs, mcmc, jags

I am using a multinomial model (I have 4 modalities) where I want to estimate all parameters of the model (6 parameters as I have 2 parameters for each of the three first modalities). I managed to do that. My problem now is that I would like to add a constraint on parameters so that my probability for the first modality is decreasing with my covariate `x`.

Therefore I calculate that I need to have:

```
beta1^(1) + sum_(k=1 to 3) (beta1^(1)-beta1^(k)).exp(beta0^(k)+beta1^(k).x) < 0
```

I am using the `runjags` package of R that uses JAGS. I would like that for each sample this constraint is respected. Is it possibile to do that?

Normally I used a C/C++ library where at each iteration, I check the condition and resample all parameters for this iteration if the condition is not fulfilled. But I can't find how to do that with JAGS (and for collaboration reasons, I can't use C).

Here is the current code:

```
model <- "model{
  for(j in 1:(nb_rep-1)) {
    beta1[j] ~ dnorm(0, 0.1)
  }
  for(j in 1:(nb_rep-1)) {
    beta0[j] ~ dnorm(0, 0.01)
  }

  for(i in 1:n){
    y_eff[i] ~ dcat(q[i,1:nb_rep])
    for(k in 1:(nb_rep-1)){
      cal_exp[i,k] <- exp(beta0[k] + beta1[k]*x_eff[i])    
    }
    sum_exp[i] <- sum(cal_exp[i,1:(nb_rep-1)])
    for(j in 1:(nb_rep-1)){     
      q[i,j] <- exp(beta0[j] + beta1[j]*x_eff[i]) / (1 + sum_exp[i])
    }
    q[i,nb_rep] <- 1 - sum(q[i,1:(nb_rep-1)])
  }
}"
```

Thank you in adavance for your help,

Best